# Visual studio is giving compile time error with angular 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, npm

I am starting with Angular 2.0. I am working with steps mention here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

When I quick download this application and run the application from command prompt after npm install command it works fine but when I am trying to run it on Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 I am getting compile time error `Build:Unknown compiler option 'lib'` and a `Warning No compiler log specified, 'Clean' won't work`. I have tried to change the TypeScript Variable to 2.1 now but issue is not resolved. Again when I run VS code through command prompt or ignore the compiletime error application is starting normally.

UPDATE 1: tsconfig.json File content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: Make sure that you have this installed. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Yes, I have installed it, thanks.

Comment: You may have an old version of TypeScript installed. `cmd > tsc -v` `cmd > where tsc`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Versions are all correct node -v  v6.9.1; npm -v 4.0.3; tsc -v 2.1.4

Comment: That's precisely what you should have.